# Java naming convention - using "try" prefix to seperate exception handling

Tags: java, naming-conventions

According to Robert C. Martin's "Clean Code" exception handling should be proceed in a separate method. In one example author use "try" (or "tryTo") prefix to distinct public method and private method performing appropriate logic as bellow.

```
public void doSomething() {
    try {
        tryToDoSomething();
    catch (Exception ex) {
        //handle exception
    }
}

public void tryDoSomething() throws Exception {
    // appropriate logic
}
```

Is this a correct convention? Maybe method names should be inverse? Would it be better to prefix method with "try" that contains try-catch block as below (similar to C# convention)?

```
public void tryDoSomething() {
    try {
        doSomething();
    catch (Exception ex) {
        //handle exception
    }
}

public void doSomething() throws Exception {
    // appropriate logic
}
```

In the first approach public method name is shorter and easier to understand.
On the other side to make a code consistent I should prefix every method that throws an exception.
What convention do you prefer?

What name do you prefer for exception variables in try-catch block - exception, ex, e?  It's a detail but I'm really interested. ;)

Comment: I guess it's an opinion but the point is that the prefix "try" should be read as "probably throws some exceptions every now and then, beware", not "it's a wrapper for try-catch-possibly-finally, please look to the non-prefixed variant". The former is behavior wise less surprising than latter and serves a well defined role instead of "just skip me".

Comment: I usually use the capitals of the exception, `Exception e`, `IOException ioe`, `NullPointerException npe` etc, unless I'm having conflicts like `double e=Math.E`, then I use `Exception exc`

Comment: First things first, you should never catch `Exception` directly; don't forget that `RuntimeException` extends `Exception`.

Comment: Personally I would use `doSomething()` for the surrounding method and `tryToDoSomething()` for the `try-catch-method`. That's because (as you already said) otherwise you would have to name every method that might throw an Exception like `try..Whatever` and in addition, the `tryToDoSomething` should be only for one small part of the whole `doSomething` (the small part that throws the exception). So it does not actually do everything of the *something* but only some part of it :)

Comment: As long as the method name tells me what the method is going to do and is as concise as possible, I'm happy. Most competent programmers I think will find out it will throw an exception because of the `throws` clause (IDE will notify you after calling the method). Java Docs are useful to let a programmer know too. This is purely an opinion-based question, but I do enjoy seeing how others write their code and why.

Comment: *"What convention do you prefer?"*, *"What name do you prefer ..."*. Please read the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). This is there as an example of a bad question for StackOverflow: "Avoid asking subjective questions where every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”"

Comment: If first method is `update` I've been using `updateNoCatch` for the one having no try-catch. But I think _try_ is better and we don't need _To_, I would just call the one surrounded by try-catch `update` and the one not surrounded `tryUpdate`. `update` would be public and `tryUpdate` would be private.